# jQuery.post returns 400 bad request error [rails]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, balanced-payments

I am using rails 4 and balanced.js and am trying to post the returned token to the back end using jQuery.post. I have the correct url getting passed but receive a 400 error. TO CLARIFY: I am getting an error on the jquery.ajax after receiving a valid token from balanced.

```
jQuery ->
$('#cc-submit').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()

    handleResponse = (response) ->
        if (response.status_code == 201)

            fundingInstrument = (if response.cards? then response.cards[0] else response.bank_accounts[0])

            alert(fundingInstrument.href)

            $('#tablecharge_uri').val(fundingInstrument.href)

            url = '/events/' + urlid + '/tablecharges'

            alert(url)

            jQuery.ajax({type: "POST", url: url, data: {uri: fundingInstrument.href, event_id: urlid}, sucess: (data) ->
                alert data.id
            error: (data) ->
                alert "not cool"})

        else
            alert(response.status + JSON.stringify(response, false, 1))

    payload = {
    name: $('#cc-name').val()
    number: $('#cc-number').val()
    expiration_month: $('#cc-expiration-month').val()
    expiration_year: $('#cc-expiration-year').val()
    ccv: $('#cc-ccv').val()
    }

    balanced.card.create(payload, handleResponse)
```

here is my controller:

```
class TablechargesController < ApplicationController
def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @table = @event.tablecharges.build
end

def index
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @table = @event.tablecharges.all
end

def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @table = @event.tablecharges.build(table_charge_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render json: 'Your message', status: :ok } 
    end
    if @table.save
        redirect_to @event, :notice => "Thanks for the cash"
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private

def table_charge_params
    params.require(:tablecharge).permit(:name, :email)
end
```

end

here is my model:

```
class Tablecharge < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event
attr_accessor :cc_name
attr_accessor :cc_number
attr_accessor :cc_expiration_month
attr_accessor :cc_expiration_year
attr_accessor :cc_ccv
end
```

UPDATE:
here is the full error code from the chrome debugger:

```
POST "/events/7/tablecharges" 400 (Bad Request) 
jquery.js?body=1:9632
send jquery.js?body=1:9632
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js?body=1:9177
handleResponse tablecharges.js?body=1:13
ret balanced.js:433
window.(anonymous function) balanced.js:395
(anonymous function)
```

UPDATE 2:
here is the error from rails server

```
 ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty
 actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:183:in `require'
```

Comment: What is the text of the 400 error you are receiving?

Comment: POST http://localhost:3000/events/7/tablecharges 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: What is the FULL text? 400 errors from Balanced indicate exactly what was malformed in the request.

Comment: oh the problem is within jQuery.ajax not balance.card.create. balanced.js is giving me the correct token i just cant post it to the backend?

Comment: @adminbanks In `url = '/events/' + urlid + '/tablecharges'` i don't see urlid defined in your function

Comment: urlid is a function thats a javascript tag in the view. the url renders how it should. i dont believe thats why i am getting the error. the rails console error is: param is missing or the value is empty

Comment: I'm having this error too and can't find the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Your data payload lacks the key "table_charge"

JS

```
data: {uri: fundingInstrument.href, event_id: urlid}
...
```

RAILS

```
def table_charge_params
    params.require(:tablecharge).permit(:name, :email)
end
```

**require** is pretty descriptive here, it blows up if the key is absent